# Form fields in acordina are not geting validated

Tags: jquery-validate, accordion

I am using validationEngine for validating form fields. I have tab and inside the tab, I have two accordions. Each accordion has 4 fields. When I submit, only first accordion form fields that are opened are getting validated. Is there any way I can force to validate all the form fields and open all accordions to show the required field message? Thank you!

```
<div id="tabs-1">

    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Select Agent</h3> <!-- First accordion title) -->
        <fieldset>
            <div>
            <label >Agent Name or ID</label>    
            <input name="insuredFirsName" title="type &quot;Agent name or id &quot;" class="validate[required] text-input"  type="text" >
            </div>
            <label>Age</label>              
            <input type="text" name="age" value="${ajaxForm.age}"  maxlength="3" size="3" class="validate[required] text-input" >
        </fieldset>

        <h3>Application Details</h3>    <!-- Second accordion title) -->

        <fieldset>  
            <div>
             <label>Contract State</label>
             <select name="State" id="State" class="validate[required]">
                 <option value="">Choose a State</option>                   
                 <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                 <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div>
            <label>Application Number :</label> 
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req" />                        
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>Application Number :</label> 
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req1" id="req1" />                      
            </div>

        </fieldset> 


    </div> <!-- Accordion close -->

    <html:button property="button1"  value ="Submit"></html:button>
</div> <!-- Tab-1 close -->
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little late but I had this same problem, i searched on the internet and found a solution, but this will work for you:

jQuery("#digitale-aanvraag").validationEngine({
      validateNonVisibleFields: true,
});

Your fields in an accordion are set to hidden so as default the validator would skip them.

Be aware that if you use this in a wizard, it won't work, because those fields are also hidden...

Anyway, GL!